# align text inside the "input select"

Tags: html, css, forms, input

i have a simple form with css, and there is a select with this style:

```
.mysub_item select {
    height: 29px;
    width: 142px;
    background: url("/images/input-background.png") no-repeat scroll 0 4px transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4B4B4D;
}
```

and the text inside that select is always align to the top and left; is there a way that i can move that text?

surprise that IE7, IE8 and IE9 set that text center vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to add padding to the style and then adjust the height and width accordingly.

e.g.

```
padding: 5px;
```

Height now equals your original height - 10px ( 5px padding on the top and bottom )
Width now equals your original width - 10px ( 5px padding on the left and right )

Also as @peduarte suggested, you can add `line-height` which actually gives the same sort of results as padding.

Comment: Just to add to that, line-height can be useful too to make that height cross-browser.

Comment: that just was a surprise, because i put a padding like @TimBJames and that works, but without reduce the height and width: [image](http://sinapsisperu.com/armandfp/a/select-center-align.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to the CSS

```
text-align:center
```

Comment: i dont want to make center, i just want something like padding: 3px 0 0 5px; only for the text inside the select, not for the select.

Answer (score 0):

try this, may help you

```
.mysub_item select {
    height: 29px;
    width: 142px;
    background: url("/images/input-background.png") no-repeat scroll 0 4px transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4B4B4D;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1.8;
}
```

Comment: just put you html portion for this stylesheet i check tell u whats a problem

Answer (score 0):

Change height to  `height: 22px;`